# What should GZ_SIM_RESOURCE_PATH be pointing to?

Tags: simulation, gazebo-7, px4

[image: Picture of GZ_SIM_RESOURCE_PATH Error for gz_bridge]

Hi I am having trouble what my GZ_SIM_RESOURCE_PATH should be pointing to. Should it be pointing to a folder of models? worlds? both? Anyone have any recommendations of what I should do to resolve this error?

I am using:
Ubuntu 22
Gazebo 7.7.0
Ros 2 Humble (but I have also tried it with a fresh install without ROS and I still get the error)

Comment: Please paste any console output as code formatted text and not as a screenshot. Screenshots are not text searchable, [amongst other things...](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Answer (score 0):

The `GZ_SIM_RESOURCE_PATH`must point to your world folder, models folder and - if required - to your meshes folder.

Regarding the error: How do you set the `GZ_SIM_RESOURCE_PATH` variable?
Please provide your launch script and hook files if you have those.